# Installed j2cli and jinja2 with pip3 but can not find out how to run j2cli

Tags: python, pip, jinja2

I installed on MacOS python, pip, upgraded it to pip3, then installed jinja2 and j2cli.
How should I run j2cli?

```
$ pip3 show jinja2
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.11.2
Summary: A very fast and expressive template engine.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: MarkupSafe
Required-by: j2cli

$ pip3 show j2cli
Name: j2cli
Version: 0.3.10
Summary: Command-line interface to Jinja2 for templating in shell scripts.
Home-page: https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli
Author: Mark Vartanyan
Author-email: kolypto@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: jinja2
Required-by:
```

Comment: `pip3 show --files j2cli | grep /bin/`

Answer (score 4):

Solution is NOT to install jinja2 prior to j2cli.
I did it because of excessive thinking: since j2cli is interface to the language jinja2, the latter should be installed first. It was wrong.
I uninstall them both with 'pip3 uninstall' command and then installed just j2cli
with 'pip3 install j2cli'. Immediately 'j2' command became available.

Comment: Had to come back here and comment. This solved it for me.